# Elasticsearch aggregations: is it possible to reference filter/query data in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql-aggregation

so consider this data:

**Mapping**

```
{
    "testIndex": {
        "mappings": {
            "testType": {
                "properties": {
                    "eventType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "eventStarted": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "eventEnded": {
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and some sample data to understand what's what

```
{    
    "eventType" : "type1",
    "eventStarted" "2014-09-01 08:00:01",
    "eventEnded" "2014-09-01 09:21:57"
},
{    
    "eventType" : "type1",
    "eventStarted" "2014-09-01 10:01:07",
    "eventEnded" "2014-09-01 10:28:11"
},
{    
    "eventType" : "type2",
    "eventStarted" "2014-09-01 09:13:46",
    "eventEnded" "2014-08-11 09:21:51"
},
{    
    "eventType" : "type3",
    "eventStarted" "2014-08-11 10:13:46",
    "eventEnded" "2014-08-11 10:21:51"
}
...
```

The idea is that there are events which happens independently every now and then and we log when they begin and when they end.

What I need is to make an aggregation but I can't think of a way without having some external script.

Aggregation should give me: list of all **eventTypes** which happens 10min to 0min before **eventType** **"type1"** begins and ends after that **"type1"** begins.

And I need to do it not to a specific "type1" event but to all of them, so my aggregation should have a bucket for each **"type1"** event and then in that bucket a list of types that happens up to 10min before **"type1"** but ends after type1 begins with a count of how many of those types we found for this instance.

So from what I understand I need some sort of way to to make a query/filter to get all type1 events and then somehow reference date fields of my results in my aggregation, but I can't find how or if it's possible at all.

I hope that makes sense.

Sorry for the long question but I thought this abstract example would make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch aggregations build buckets that only depend on properties of the current document. Here you are trying to build buckets based on values of other documents (conceptually this is a join) -- this is not possible.

Comment: thanks for the answer, would it be possible if I would restructure my data or the outside script and looping is the only way?